# Is it possible to open Android screen from a background application?

Tags: android, android-screen

I have an application which runs in background. The application aims to open the screen. My phone does not set any password. Is it possible to open the screen from my application by code? Thank you

Comment: If the screen is within your application only, you can display it in even a locked phone from background

Comment: No. The screen of my phone. When I did not use my phone, the phone will automatically lock. I want to use (after 1 mins) the app. will automatic unlock it and display home

Answer (score 0):

Using intent to call your application.

Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

 intent.setClassName("your.package","your.package.Activity");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You have to add **intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**

Comment: Thanks, it means I can unlock my screen from applicaiton service( my screen has no password). Is it right?

Comment: you want turn on your application in the sleep mode?

Comment: in that case, search the wake lock.

Comment: But can I call it from a service application?